# Convert VMDK to LVM

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to migrate a VM from my laptop to my XEN server.

First I used

```
$ vboxmanage clonehd my-disk.vmdk -format RAW mydisk.img
```

Copy to the server and do the following

```
$ kvm-img my-disk.img
image: my-disk.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 18G (19327352832 bytes)
disk size: 18G

# lvcreate -L20G my_vgs -n mydisk
# dd if=my-disk.img of=/dev/my_vgs/mydisk
```

Now when I try to mount I get an error

```
# mount /dev/my_vgs/mydisk /mnt
# mount -t ext4 /dev/my_vgs/mydisk /mnt

VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

**What did I do wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem the vmdk file don't have a partition, the file has the whole disk. So I used the 'skip' and 'count' dd's options for specific the partition and works fine

For get the offsets i use the command `sfdisk`

```
$ sfdisk -l -uS my-disk.img 

my-disk.img1   *      2048  36702207   36700160  83  Linux
my-disk.img2      36704254  37746687    1042434   5  Extendida
my-disk.img3             0         -          0   0  Vacía
my-disk.img4             0         -          0   0  Vacía
my-disk.img5      36704256  37746687    1042432  82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Then ran the command `dd` again

```
# dd if=my-disk.img of=/dev/my_vgs/mydisk skip=2048 count=36702207
```

### Optional

```
# e2fsck -f /dev/my_vgs/mydisk
# resize2fs /dev/my_vgs/mydisk
```

Comment: Congrats! :) You could include some info on how to get those offsets, [like this](http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20:loop-mounting-partitions-from-a-disk-image/).

Comment: Check the update @DanielB